# Does 'bite' in surgery equal 'stitch'?

Tags: word-meaning

I've struck upon these uses of the noun 'bite' in texts related to surgery:

> This distance is marked on the sclera with the caliper, and 7-0 or 8-0 double-armed polyglactin suture is used to place 2 radial **bites** on either side of the mark. These **bites** should be about 1.5 mm long and 1.5 mm from each other. ([at Emedicine](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1844160-overview#a15))

and

> Most corneal surgeons prefer deep partial-thickness corneal suture **bites** over full-thickness **bites**. Incorporating 95% of the donor’s and host’s relative corneal thickness avoids posterior wound gape. Full-thickness **bites** may be associated with a higher chance of leakage along suture tracks and serve as a portal of entry for microorganisms or epithelial ingrowth. ([at Ophthalmic News Network](http://one.aao.org/bcscsnippetdetail.aspx?id=e0ffc86a-3fad-4401-8534-4b2744e5ea58))

and

> Long scleral suture **bites** are recommended to reduce the risk of the sutures cheese-wiring out of the sclera when the sutures are tied. ([Strabismus surgery](http://books.google.ru/books?id=4oqo-LMSV_kC&lpg=PA151&dq=suture%20%22bites%22&hl=ru&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q=suture%20%22bites%22&f=false))

Does this use of **bite** make it equal to the word **stitch** (a single pass of a needle; the resulting loop of the thread)? Or are there nuances of meaning differentiating the two words?

Answer (score 1):

It's referred to each thread of the stitch. It's a surgical term.

[image]

Recently, [one research showed](http://www.generalsurgerynews.com/PrintArticle.aspx?A_Id=27647&D_Id=69&D=In%20the%20News) that ‘Small Bites’ drop rate of incisional hernias.

Comment: Thanks, Maulik! I'm thinking of adding this sense to Wiktionary's entry on *bite*, hence my question, to make sure.

Comment: Sure...go ahead. :) But be careful if you are writing the definition. I expressed it the way I understand.

Comment: It occured to me that I was possibly wrong: a stitch may have a fragment that goes *above* the patient's tissue. This fragment is not part of *the bite*. The part of the stitch that travels through the tissue is *the bite*. Hence, a *vertical mattress stitch* has two *bites*: one is shallower, the other is deeper in the tissue, and two small fragments that go above, these are not part of the bites. "It was a hard thing to undo this knot" (c) At the first bite, at least. (0:

Answer (score 1):

I've read up some more, and it seems that *bite* is the penetration portion of a stitch, that is, the part of the stitch that goes through the tissue itself. The part of the stitch that goes above the patient's tissue is not a *bite*. Moreover, in surgery, the term *suture* is the preferred choice, not *stitch*, but the two seem to be interchangeable.

A long bite, of course, will result in a long stitch, but the terms are different. Consider the following quote:

> A long **stitch** is the result of a large **bite** with the largest portion of fascia possible, aiming to increase tensile strength and to decrease the risk of fascial dehiscence. ([Harlaal et al; BMC Surgery, 2011](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2482/11/20))

Take a look at the [vertical mattress stitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_mattress_stitch):

[image]

This is how it is described in "[Basic Surgical Techniques](http://books.google.ru/books?id=M8U1FhEj5S0C&lpg=SA3-PA65&dq=%22mattress%20stitch%22%20two%20bites&hl=ru&pg=SA3-PA65#v=onepage&q=%22mattress%20stitch%22%20two%20bites&f=false)":

> If the entry and exit holes are perpendicular to the edges, one **bite** is smaller than the other, this is a vertical or longitudinal mattress stitch.

Hence, each single stitch of this type comprises two *bites*, one lying a bit deeper in the tissue, the other lying above it, and two small portions on the surface.

And here is the [horisontal mattress stitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_mattress_stitch):

[image]

Here's the schematic representation - the two dashed lines mark the two *bites*, the parts of the stitch that go under the skin:

[image]