# what does ''leaving" or "pulling'' refer to?

Tags: grammar

*Source : Comprehensive Textbook of Surgery*

There is a figure in this book and it says :

> To begin tying the final knot, take a bite from superficial to deep and then deep to superficial, **leaving** a loop between the bites.

> Tie four simple throws, **pulling** lengthwise along the incision line to appose skin edges.

leaving and pulling ? what does it refer to ? ( by pulling, throws which pull ? or whatever ?...)

Comment: Have you looked those words up in a dictionary? They're both used in the normal senses.

Comment: bite :  needle penetration

Comment: You asked about "leave" and "pull". Did you look them up?

Comment: I think you mean [bight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bight_(knot))

Comment: Generally, "while pulling" or "while leaving" would have the same meaning - the participle describes something that happens at the same time. (Is there a reference that can explain this?)

Comment: I question the use of the word *bite* in that text. Please see the definitions of the word here: https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Bite+(medical), This sounds like it was not written by an English speaker.

Comment: In the process of doing what the sentence tells you, you must leave a loop/pull lengthwise.

Comment: If bite is needle penetration, then this: "take a bite from superficial to deep" makes no sense. Is all this a translation from some language?

Comment: I have always had a three-pronged rule for translation: Don't kill the patient. (medical) Don't perplex the judge. (legal) and Don't mistake which lever to pull. (technical). This fails the first truism.

Comment: It seems that "bite" is the word used by surgeons. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29524/does-bite-in-surgery-equal-stitch

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking if "leaving" means "by leaving" or "which leave", and, similarly, if "pulling" means "by pulling" or "which pull".

In both cases, it's the latter.

The fact that you are even asking indicates that you already know how the options differ in meaning, but in case not @Stuart F explains the "which" versions in his comment (although he uses "while").

Overall, though, I can see the confusion. And it's not helped by the original text's misspelling of "bight" as "bite", nor the use of "appose", which is uncommon and a bit archaic (although maybe it's common in surgery -- it does tend to have a lot of archaic words). The unusual use of "throw" also adds to the cognitive dissonance of the whole thing. Having checked a bunch of sources, I now see that in this context a "throw" is a self-contained component -- a "sub-knot", if you will -- of a more complex knot. But I've had to infer that; I could not find an explicit and precise definition.

---

NOTE: I didn't want to mention this in the above, so as not to add more complexity, but this is ELL after all, so I feel I should add. You compare the "by..." and "which..." forms; e.g. "by pulling" versus "which pull". It's arguable that you should instead be thinking of "by pulling" versus "**that** pull". "That" may be more appropriate than "which" if the text is part of a restrictive clause. For my part (native speaker), I've never been able to remember which is which, nor care about the alleged difference, but this is, as I say, ELL, so I thought I'd mention it. For a good way to avoid even worrying about the that/which difference, I refer you again to @Stuart F's comment, which skillfully avoided the issue (and was, strictly, more accurate than either "which" or "that").

Comment: I think the verb "appose" ***is*** used in the fields of anatomy and surgery more often than elsewhere, so the problem is more that OP is trying to understand complex domain-specific things while working in a foreign language, not that the text he's looking at is "non-standard" as such.

Comment: The text is full of mistakes and is probably Chinglish. That's my guess.

Comment: Bite seems correct, see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29524/does-bite-in-surgery-equal-stitch